# JTree with MVC.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jstree

Hi i wanted to use JTree plugin to my MVC.net project but i encountered some problems. I am following [JTree Overview](http://www.jstree.com/) and later HTML Data.

I have added a folder to Solution called 'JTree' and copied all files from 'dist' folder from JTree download.

Next I want to use HTML data to test if the plugin works, but unfortunetly all i can see is the basic ul - li list.

Here is my View code

```
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Index"
End Code

<link rel="stylesheet" href="JTree/themes/default/style.min.css" />

<script src="JTree/jstree.min.js"></script>
<script src="JTree/libs/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { $('#html1').jstree(); });
</script>


<div id="html1">
  <ul>
    <li>
        Root node 1
        <ul>
            <li>Child node 1</li>
            <li><a href="#">Child node 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The same code works as a simple .html file written in notepad

Comment: any console errors???

Comment: nope - i the plugin just doesnt work

Comment: just reorder your js files..

Comment: changing order did not work

Comment: i copied the code to simple html site written in notepad and it works ... i have no idea what's up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to load jquery and then you have to load the tree plugin.
Are you sure the files are correct? jquery.js look like me that the path is wrong...

Comment: jquery is inside lib folder in JTree so path is good But i'm gonna change order

Comment: Check your developer tools of your browser to see if you have a 404 or script error. Is your jquery version higher than 1.9? 1.9 or higher is required.

Comment: yeah i have 404 error - so i am not correctly giving addres to file right?

Comment: i got rid of 404 errosr but i still get :

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: ok i had to delete the old jquery files becouse there was conflickt :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to include a "JTree/jstree.min.js" file after the jquery lib?